# WPF: New Row on Datagrid that bind to custom class

Tags: wpf, class, datagrid

I created some custom data container class with `OnPropertyChanged event` and `ObservableCollection` and bind it to datagrid in WPF. *The problem is everytime the program start, the datagrid automatically creates a new row at the bottom.* This new row is not present in my ObservableCollection so editing it will be useless, as adding new item programmatically in my ObservableCollection will erase the data in the new row.

How can I disable the new row or make my ObservableCollection updated if user start editing in new row (just like in SQL Server management Studio)?

nb: If you can please give me an example of "correct" custom class in WPF, I'm still in WPF.

Comment: If you just want to disable that users can add new rows then set `CanUserAddRows="False"` in the `DataGrid`. The `NewItemPlaceHolder` that is the empty row, will be inserted into the `ObservableCollection` upon commit

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do what you say and it works. unfortunately i cannot mark your comment as answer.

Comment: @Meleak Would you please post your comment as answer? I did it in first thought as community wiki but I would prefer to have you as author and delete my community answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Meleak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318425/meleak)'s answer from comment:

If you just want to disable that users can add new rows then set `CanUserAddRows="False"` in the `DataGrid`. The `NewItemPlaceHolder` that is the empty row, will be inserted into the `ObservableCollection` upon commit.